# color based off multiple values in grafana stat panel

Tags: grafana

I'm using a single stat panel where the values can either be 0,1,2,3,6,7. Is there a way that I can define the color for each value separately? I see the thresholds but it seems it can only do it off of three values? Can I do this based of more than 3 values and with different colors each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently not possible. There is a feature request for support for multiple thresholds so hopefully a PR will come for it soon:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3608